# I'm looping over an array and modifying the contents of the array, but I don't get the results I expect.

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

I'm looping over an array and modifying the contents of the array, but I don't get the results I expect. What am I missing or doing wrong?

I have two groups of divs (one with class attacker, and other enemy) with three elements each. I am trying to select one element from each side by making a border around it. Now i want to toggle classes from a attacker to enemy and the other way.
But when I use for loop it somehow ignores some elements and changes only one or two div classes. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="army1">
    <div class="attacker">
        <img src="img/Man/Archer.jpg" />
        <div class="hp"></div>
    </div>
    <br><div class="attacker">
        <img src="img/Man/Knight.jpg" />
        <div class="hp"></div>
    </div>
    <br><div class="attacker">
        <img src="img/Man/Soldier.jpg" />
        <div class="hp"></div>
    </div>
    <br>            
</div>

<div id="army2">
    <div class="enemy">
        <img src="img/Orcs/Crossbowman.jpg" />
        <div class="hp"></div>
    </div>
    <br><div class="enemy">
        <img src="img/Orcs/Mine.jpg" />
        <div class="hp"></div>
    </div>
    <br><div class="enemy">
        <img src="img/Orcs/Pikeman.jpg" />
        <div class="hp"></div>
    </div>
    <br>            
</div>
```

And my javascript code:

```
var attacker = document.getElementsByClassName('attacker');
var enemy = document.getElementsByClassName('enemy');


var button = document.getElementById("fight");

// var class1 = document.getElementsByClassName("first")[0].getAttribute("class");
// class1 = class1.split(" ");

//choose attacker
for (var i = 0; i < attacker.length; i++) {
    attacker[i].onclick = function () {
        //select only one attacker and set its id to attackerid
        if (this.getAttribute('class') != 'attacker first') {
            resetAttackerClasses();
            this.setAttribute('class', 'attacker first');
        } else {
            resetAttackerClasses();
        }

    };
}

//choose enemy
for (var i = 0; i < enemy.length; i++) {
    enemy[i].onclick = function () {
        //select only one attacker and set its id to enemyid
        if (this.getAttribute('class') != 'enemy second') {
            resetEnemyClasses();
            this.setAttribute('class', 'enemy second');
        } else {
            resetEnemyClasses();
        }
    };
}

//fight
button.onclick = function() {
    //take off enemy health
    document.getElementsByClassName('enemy second')[0].children[1].style.width = '50px';

    resetAttackerClasses();
    resetEnemyClasses();

     for (var i = 0; i < attacker.length; i++) {
            attacker[i].setAttribute('class', 'enemy');
            enemy[i].setAttribute('class', 'attacker');
    };
};


function resetAttackerClasses() {
    for (var i = 0; i < attacker.length; i++) {
        attacker[i].setAttribute('class', 'attacker');
    };
}
function resetEnemyClasses() {
    for (var i = 0; i < attacker.length; i++) {
        enemy[i].setAttribute('class', 'enemy');
    };
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you're removing the class that was used to fetch the element, which means the element will automatically be removed from the live NodeList *(since it no longer matches the query)*.

When this happens, the NodeList is reindexed, so the next element becomes the current one, and you end up skipping over it with the next `i++`;

To fix it, iterate in reverse instead.

If you don't want to go in reverse, then decrement the index every time you remove an element from the list.

Comment: You should be able to copy it as well and then iterate over the new array:  var nodeArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(theNodeList, 0);

Comment: @lmortenson: Yes, that'll work too. Nice to avoid the copy though. If OP cares about the order, I'd rather decrement the index.